# Can readFileSync from node.js fs library load an array from a text file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My text file contains one small array (for simplicity here) of two objects as shown in array1. I want to load this text file and manipulate the array in further downstream steps. When it loads, it says it is a string, and as such prohibits array manipulation. How can load and manipulate my array after it loads?

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
var fs = require('fs');

array1 = fs.readFileSync('smallArray.txt', 'utf8');
console.log(typeof array1);
//logs string!! 

var array2 = [{"username":"one","name":"158","EF":40.745954}, {"username":"two","name":"216","EF":24.016202}; 
console.log(typeof array2);
// logs object!!
```

Comment: Always include the language you're using in your tags.

Comment: ...also, tags like "array" and "fs" generally aren't useful because they aren't specific to your language and library -- "fs" can mean "filesystem", for instance, it doesn't mean the node.js fs library universally enough that someone can search for the fs tag in StackOverflow and get a useful result (which is the kind of thing that tags here are meant to be good for).

Answer (score 1):

If smallArray.txt contains valid JSON, all you need to do is parse the contents:

```
array1 = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('smallArray.txt', 'utf8'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data in the file is valid JSON and you rename `smallArray.txt` to `smallArray.json`, you can just use `require()` and it will automatically parse it like this:

```
var array1 = require('smallArray.json');
```

Comment: @AttonRand - Since it appears you may be new here, if this answered your question you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer to mark it as the best answer.  This will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.