# Hyperledger Composer: Access files on local system

Tags: javascript, file-upload, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I want to access the files from the local system, so that I can upload them to a cloud and store the link on the blockchain. Is there a way to access the files through the .js script files in Hyperledger Composer?

Answer (score 1):

So technically, this is a Node question (for file upload) and and semantically a modeling question. First and foremost, this is (from a Composer perspective) a task that is performed from the 'client' side and the coded solution 'belongs' here. If you mean (ie interacting an Hyperledger Composer business network) how to access and store as data (String) in the business network - the answer below will provide more details. Others may answer on the 'Cloud' storage aspect. You can always store a link to the file (and a hash of the file and provide that as part of the URL / link) on the blockchain, so it can refer to the Cloud stored file.

If storing the contents is your goal, using Javascript, you can use `readFileSync` and convert to a String eg.  `fs.readFileSync(‘yourFile`).toString(‘base64’);`- you should be able to convert the image to a`Base64` string in your code. You can define 'String' for your chosen modeled Asset type etc - ie a String field to host it in the deployed Hyperledger Composer business network. The theory is that, once it is a string, it is can be updated (as a transaction, that is part of the smart contract/"chaincode") on the business network, just like any other field.

these links may also help in that regard:

[Can readFileSync from node.js fs library load an array from a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302409/can-readfilesync-from-node-js-fs-library-load-an-array-from-a-text-file)

Image files, PDFs:
-> https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/02/convert-an-uploaded-image-to-a-base64-string-in-node-js/

Another of a similar genre to the above:
-> https://belltane.wordpress.com/2017/03/27/storing-images-in-hyperledger-fabric-blockchain/

Comment: Thanks Paul. Does the Hyperledger Composer's js files now support Node JS? We would have to require ('fs'), which is a node component right?

Answer (score 0):

In the Transaction logic script you cannot use `require` or `import`.

The Transaction Logic is run in a chaincode (docker) container on the Fabric, so the filesystem would be the filesystem of the (docker) chaincode not where your files are stored on the client.

So you would end up writing a Client app (with access to the file system), and then calling the Transaction either through the Composer JavaScript API, or the REST API.